# Zip including hidden files

Tags: zip, hidden-files

In Linux I can zip all(except hidden files) in current directory by doing:

```
zip 1.zip *
```

But how do I include the hidden files?

Answer (score 203, accepted):

**EDIT:** The correct way is `zip -r 1.zip .`

The commands shown in my previous answer below are incorrect because they also include the parent directory.

---

Have you tried this:

```
zip yourfile.zip sourcedir/* .*
```

or you in your case

```
zip 1.zip * .[^.]*
```

It should include all hidden files also.

Comment: that pretty much works but now im also getting ../ which i dont think i want.

Comment: by ../ you mean, you are also compressing files from the directory above?

Comment: apparently. When i do zip 1.zip * .* (in a folder with subfolder a and a hidden file called '.hidden_file') i get:

Comment: adding: a/ (stored 0%)
adding: ../ (stored 0%)
adding: .hidden_file (stored 0%)

Comment: or as you said, 'zip -r 1.zip .', which also works and is simpler.

Answer (score 25):

Or you can add more simple

```
zip 1.zip ./
```

Comment: you said `zip -r 1.zip ./`

Answer (score 18):

Just to be sure it is not forgotten since this is a forum for developers and a good number of us use git.

An easy way to get only what you want in the zip is to use `git archive -o filename.zip branch`

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I needed: a lot less troubles than manually calling `zip`.

Comment: This approach doesn't include the `.git/` directory though

Comment: @ScottMcC If you needed something that was already git related, wouldn't you just clone it?

Comment: It would be nice for transferring with scp

Answer (score 7):

If you want to zip all files (+hidden files)
Kindly using: zip -r namefiles.zip .
The "." is all files in folder.

```
zip -r namefiles.zip "folder will zip"
```

Comment: How is your answer different to the accepted answer, which states "The correct way is `zip -r 1.zip .`"?

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie He also explained what "." means. That made the difference I suppose.

Comment: The "." is NOT all files in folder. It means the "current folder" itself, which would ultimately include all its contents.

Answer (score 7):

On macOS 10.15.7 I had to separatelly add all dot leading files (`\.*`) and rest of the files (`*`):

```
zip -r file.zip \.* *
```

Answer (score 2):

if you don't have rights to save zip file in current dir you can go to dir where you have rights and type

```
zip -r 1.zip /path/to/source/dir/.
```

However when if in `.../some_dir` you type

```
unzip 1.zip
```

then your files will be decompress into  `.../some_dir/path/to/source/dir/`

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to save some subdirectory of the current directory recursively with hidden and regular files just type

```
$ zip -r backup_subdirectory.zip backup_subdirectory/. backup-subdirectory/*
```

And for unzipping:

```
$ unzip backup_subdirectory.zip
```

Or even simpler by using `tar` for creating an archive:

```
$ tar czvf backup_subdirectory.tar.gz backup_subdirectory/
```

And for extracting all files from the archive:

```
$ tar xzvf backup_subdirectory.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

```
zip -r 1.zip .* -x "../*"
```

Just doing `zip -r 1.zip .*` will include the parent folder as well so the trick is to exclude the parent folder using `-x "../*"`