# Zip all files even hidden

Tags: ubuntu, zip, hidden

I am trying to zip all files from one folder . There are some hidden files and I can't get them into the archive . I am doing it on my Ubuntu server .

I tried this one

```
screen zip -r www.zip /var/www/* .*
```

The problem is , it put all folders even from /var/ inside the www.zip .
Looked at this question : [Zip including hidden files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493206/zip-including-hidden-files)
Tried it and the same result .

Comment: `zip -r www.zip /var/www/`. This was answered in the question you already mentioned, btw.

Comment: The problem was that the answer of the linked question was wrong and was not updated. I will edit it to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On linux Mint if i run

```
zip -r test.zip test/
```

i get into the zip hidden and not hidden file.

Inside test directory i have:

```
ls -la test/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 4096 gen  4 17:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 4096 gen  4  2014 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1    0 gen  4 17:06 .file2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1    0 gen  4 17:06 file.txt
```