# Does the Github Action checkout@v2 checkout .eslintrc file?

Tags: github-actions

I noticed when I was trying to run my github workflow to deploy my dockerized VUE app to Elastic Beanstalk that I kept getting an error in my logs saying no eslint config found, since I had just a handful of ignore lines.

So when I added a step in the workflow to `ls` the files being checked out, I saw it did not grab any of the files formatted as `.*`.

I would assume it should at least be getting the `.eslintrc.*` file since it is supposed to come featured to run `npm install` and `npm run lint` it would look at the checked out config file to determine if the rules pass.

Here is my workflow up to this point:

```yaml
name: Deploy to Staging Environment
on: [workflow_dispatch]
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Latest Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: List Checked Out files
        run: ls
        # DOES NOT SHOW ANY .* files checked out
```

[image]

Is anyone else noticing the same? What should I try?

Comment: Use `ls -a` instead of `ls` to show hidden files as well.

Comment: OK that worked. So I think then I need to figure out a way to run `zip -r ...` to include these hidden files.

I think I found the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12493244/5527376

Thanks for the nudge in the right direction